# How to start an android emulator in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, emulation, ubuntu-16.04

I have android sdk installed, I've looked up directions which say to run `~/android-sdk-linux/tools/android` and then click on a tools menu, but there is no tools menu.

I've also tried downloading virtual machine manager, but when I started that emulator it said I needed to insert an sd card.

How do I start an android emulator on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For **Ubuntu 16.04** you need to download few things first.

After installing Android Studio.

**Goto Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Create new virtual device**

follow standard installation for new virtual device.

After Creating virtual device

**Goto Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Tools and check Android emulator** [image]

Give it a try,if it still doesn't work you need add few libraries.

**Goto terminal and execute below commands**

`sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386`

`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

`cd YOURPATH/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64`

`mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak`

`ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++`

This should start your emulator.

Comment: An alternate to changing libstdc files around on disk is to 'export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1' before starting Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the name of the device that you want to run and then:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd NAME_OF_YOUR_DEVICE
```

In my case:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
```

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
~/android-sdk-linux/tools/android avd
```

to start in AVD manager mode.

Comment: The "android" command is deprecated use tools/bin/sdkmanager or tools/bin/avdmanager

Answer (score 0):

1. Change directory using: `cd /Path/to/Sdk/tools`
2. Start emulator using: `sudo ./emulator -avd NAME_OF_YOUR_DEVICE`